# URL Change without loading whole page in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

I am working on classified ads project in asp.net mvc3. I am facing problem in filter search page I want to change the URL without loading the whole page like Facebook or Linkedin before change:

```
http://localhost:4847/Category/Clothing/
```

after change when user remove category:

```
http://localhost:4847/Category/
```

And when user select category it should be change to append category as I show on top.

I am using ajax for filter search

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [Html5 History API](http://html5demos.com/history)

Anyway this is an Html5 feature and not all browsers may support it. In this case I would suggest directly using a plugin that degrades to hash changes if not supported, like [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js)

Comment: Leonardo, have you did it in real? I'm making my site using History.js and have some issues i don't like. First of all external identifier in url, maybe it's usedull but popular sites doesn't use it and i've always have different delimiter between hash and url part(#, !# etc). Maybe you know other plugins?

Comment: is there no other way without using html5 history api

Comment: No, there is no other way to change the url. The fallback method is by using the hash bang or directly the hash

Comment: Denis, this feature is browser dependant, so if a browser does not support History API it may fallback to hash

Comment: "It" i mean the plugin. If you use the plain History API, you have to check if the browser suppports it and fallback if it is needed

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally the same question as how to fix the browser history back-forward buttons. Checkout [What is the best back button jQuery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin), it really could help you alot!

Comment: i also try jquery address plugin but its not helped me..basically my search panel include other criteria as city,price range on ajax its working fine but on page load or refresh all search clear from page.so i want when user select any criteria it append in url on remove it should also remove from url (how to do this) or (there is any other way to do this so onload the page search that user made should not clear)

Comment: you have to save the information the user fills in in a session or cookie or something like that. But this has nothing to do with ajax...